# rename files to contain a parental directory

Tags: macos, bash

I want to rename png files under some directories. New file names should be directory name concatenated one, like DirectoryNameFileName.png.
I thought the command must be as follows, but this doesn't  work properly. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.
My environment is Mac OSX GNU bash.

```
find . -name '*.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv {} ./{basename `pwd`}{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this gets your desired output:

```
find . -name '*.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv {} "./$(basename "$(pwd)"){}"' \;
```

Incidentally, this is a good example of why the `$()` syntax is preferred over backticks `` ` `` for command substitution, as it makes nesting a lot easier. 
You can possibly use the shell variable `$PWD` instead of calling the command `pwd`:

```
find . -name '*.png' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv {} "./$(basename "$PWD"){}"' \;
```

I'm not able to test it at the moment but may need to use `-execdir` rather than `-exec`, so that the command is run from the directory that each file is found, rather than from the one that you run `find` from.